# database insertion working well on android emulator but not on device

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have created a database using [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/119293/Using-SQLite-Database-with-Android).

When I insert the values in my table, it works on the emulator and I have seen the values are inserted correctly. But when I run my application on a device, it gives me this error:

```
02-29 17:30:45.341: E/Database(3300):android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:no such   table: recently_used: , while compiling: INSERT INTO recently_used(iconsset_name, icon_name) VALUES(?, ?); 
02-29 17:30:45.341: E/Database(3300):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method) 
02-29 17:30:45.341: E/Database(3300):at   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92) 
02-29 17:30:45.341: E/Database(3300):at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
02-29 17:30:45.341: E/Database(3300):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83) 
02-29 17:30:45.341: E/Database(3300):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>  (SQLiteStatement.java:41)
```

Here is my database class.

```
public class DBHelpter extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DatabaseName.db";

    public static final String ICONS_SET_TABLE_NAME = "iconset";
    public static final String ID_ICONS_SET = "_id";
    public static final String NAME_ICONS_SET ="name";
    public static final String SERVER_ID_ICONS_SET = "serverid";
    public static final String PRODUCT_ID_ICONSET = "productid";

    public static final String ICON_TABLE_NAME = "icons";
    public static final String ID_ICONS = "_id";

    public static final String SERVER_ICON_ID = "serverid";
    public static final String ICONSET_ID_ICONS = "iconsetid";

    public static final String RECENTLY_USED_TABLE_NAME = "recently_used";
    public static final String ICONS_NAME_RECENTLY = "icon_name";
    public static final String ICONSSET_NAME_RECENTLY = "iconsset_name";
    public static final String RECENTLY_ICONSET_ID = "_id";


    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION_NO = 3;
    public Context mContext = null;

    public static final String mIconsSetQuery = "CREATE TABLE "+ICONS_SET_TABLE_NAME + "(" + ID_ICONS_SET +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + NAME_ICONS_SET +" TEXT," + SERVER_ID_ICONS_SET +" INTEGER," + PRODUCT_ID_ICONSET +" TEXT);";
    public static final String mIcons = "CREATE TABLE "+ ICON_TABLE_NAME + "(" + ID_ICONS+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT,"+ SERVER_ICON_ID + " INTEGER,"+ICONSET_ID_ICONS + " INTEGER);";
    public static final String recently_table_query = "CREATE TABLE "+ RECENTLY_USED_TABLE_NAME + "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, icon_name TEXT,iconsset_name TEXT);";

    public DBHelpter(Context context) {

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION_NO);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized SQLiteDatabase getReadableDatabase() {
        return super.getReadableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase() {
        return super.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(mIconsSetQuery);
        db.execSQL(mIcons);
        db.execSQL(recently_table_query);

    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onOpen(db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + ICONS_SET_TABLE_NAME);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + ICON_TABLE_NAME);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + RECENTLY_USED_TABLE_NAME);

        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Here is the method i am using.

```
public void recentlyUsed(RecentlyUsedIcons recentlyUsedIcons) {
     values.put(DBHelpter.ICONS_NAME_RECENTLY, recentlyUsedIcons.getIcon_name());
     values.put(DBHelpter.ICONSSET_NAME_RECENTLY, recentlyUsedIcons.getIconSet_name());
     mDatabase.insert(DBHelpter.RECENTLY_USED_TABLE_NAME, null, values);
}
```

Comment: Looks like your `onCreate()` for the database doesn't work correctly. Try deinstalling your app on the emulator and install it again. You should get the same error there. Can you post your database class?

Comment: I have un-intalled and re-installed the application. but it is working in emulator. but on device its giving error.

Comment: Can you please show us how you try to insert? The database class looks good.

Comment: values.put(DBHelpter.ICONS_NAME_RECENTLY, recentlyUsedIcons.getIcon_name());
    values.put(DBHelpter.ICONSSET_NAME_RECENTLY, recentlyUsedIcons.getIconSet_name());
    
    mDatabase.insert(DBHelpter.RECENTLY_USED_TABLE_NAME, null, values);

Comment: In the post, please, and if possible the complete method.

Comment: I have added a method as well. but my problem is that it is working in emulator, but not working on device. how is that so? what could be the reason of that?.

Comment: That is a good question. I don't know where you initialize `values` you use in your insert method, but it looks good so far. I guess you need to run your code with a debugger and check that every method is executed in the correct order... maybe the device is too fast and the database is not yet finished to be created. Sorry, but I have no more ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem too

```
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION_NO = 3;
```

I changed my database version `1` to `2`, after that it has been working.
Change it to `4` and try to recompile on your phone again. I hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the old database was still stored inside the device, there are two ways to resolve the problem:

1. try to clear application data and uninstall the application from the device and install it again.
2. upgrading the existing database version by seting database version to (for example) `vers_no` + 1 in your code.

Comment: Please take while to improve spelling and grammar of your post, before you post it.

Comment: Thank you. I will take you notes into consideration.